# Error NullPointerexception Custom Actionbar

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

i am getting an error NullPointerException at Actionbar.setCustomView();

im my class i am extending with Collection can anyone help me ?

Comment: show us your code. then we might help you

Comment: I don't know what about others, but I'm not a mind reader.

Comment: @PhilippSander     well for Source code [Use this link](https://www.github.com/Gupta126/code/blob/master/mainfile) in this file i am getting error at line number 96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your Actionbar object if its null and build up from there. How do you get the Actionbar object?

Comment: I am getting actionbar object like `Actionbar action = getActionBar();`

Comment: ok then check according to your application settings why your object is null.. whats your target api?

Comment: target api is 18. well tell me one thing if i am extending Activity so that can make error?

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: [use this link](https://www.github.com/Gupta126/code/blob/master/mainfile) error at line 96

Comment: Is the title of your window visible? see if that blog solves your issue... http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html...

Comment: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);==> that might be your problem

Comment: Thank You man its worked..... cab you tell me how to make actionbar transperent ?

Comment: Thank You man its worked..... can you tell me how to make actionbar transperent ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setCustomView(view);
```

> Note: Actionbar works only in Android 3.0 and above.. Still if you need Actionbar in other devices (Android 2.3 and below) as well, use ActionbarSherlock (http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i am getting at ab.setCustomView(view); error is NullPointerException